# Can I use an apple pay button in a cordova app?

Tags: reactjs, cordova, dns, payment, applepay

I've read every domain that has an "Apple Pay" button should be registered in the developer account. If I wanted to use apple pay in a cordova app (I wanted to use stripe js react, and the apple pay button) how would I do such thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Apple Pay plugin for Cordova hasn’t been updated for a while now you can check it out.
It supports iOS up to 13.3 according to the latest issues on the repo
https://github.com/samkelleher/cordova-plugin-applepay

Now sure if that will work but you can try looking into Apple Pay JS library.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web/apple_pay_js_api